Is there a disassembly of the Amiga's dos.library available?
I've become interested in how the Amiga's LoadSeg() function from dos.library works.
So I'm looking for commented disassemblies of any version of the dos.library from an Amiga ROM or Kickstart etc.
I can find disassemblies of exec.library, ramdrive.device, and disk.resource, but so far nothing that includes dos.library - but I haven't been in the Amiga scene for a long time so other than Google I don't know where to look.

I assume there would be a reimplementation in AROS for the dos.library

@JoakimElofsson Nice idea! I'd still like to see one of the original implementations, but internalloadseg_aos.c is definitely going to be useful in the meantime.

Be careful what you wish for :-) dos.library is weird, owing to it being written in BCPL in the Kickstart 1.x series. It was re-written in C for Kickstart 2.0 and later, but I can only imagine how ugly the backward-compatibility would make it look.

It might be simpler to just disassemble it on an Amiga. LoadSeg()'s jump address appears to be loaded into memory at DosBase-$96.

@KelvinSherlock Wow that's a weird collection. Lots of non-OS stuff in there and multiple copies of OS stuff. I don't know if it's original old source, late original source from after the acquisitions, or commented disassembly, but LoadSeg() and friends is in there several times.

@BrianH Yes trying that too. I used to disassemble Amiga system libraries a ton back in the mid '90s with Resource. I found an early A1000 rom yesterday and started but I've forgotten a lot. How do I locale DosBase in a rom?
